# Xamarin Forms Switch can not take value page start

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

There is a switch that I use here :

```
<Switch x:Name="serbestMiktarSwitch"   
                                 IsToggled="False"
                                Toggled="serbestMiktarSwitch_Toggled" 
                                 />
```

Switch can not take any value when page start then my processes go wrong and I got error from my service. I'm using preferences to save last value of switch but when I open that page I have to set this switch on/off again and then my processes work well.

I add product in this page and this switch changes free amount/ locked amount parameter. This "add product" process is accordiong to this switch. When user don't select it I can't get good information from service because code can't select to use method.

```
 string serbestMiktarBool = Preferences.Get("serbestMiktarTogle", "");
```

I use this function set my switch.

```
 void setSerbestMiktar()
    {
        string serbestMiktarBool = Preferences.Get("serbestMiktarTogle", "");

        if (serbestMiktarBool != null)
        {
            if (serbestMiktarBool == "0")
            {
                serbestMiktarToogle = false;
                serbestMiktarSwitch.IsToggled = false;
                serbestMiktarSwitch.ThumbColor = Color.Red;
                serbestMiktarSwitch.OnColor = Color.LightGray;
                stokCagirButton.IsEnabled = false;
                stokCagirButton.TextColor = Color.White;

            }
            else if (serbestMiktarBool == "1")
            {
                serbestMiktarToogle = true;
                serbestMiktarSwitch.IsToggled = true;
                serbestMiktarSwitch.ThumbColor = Color.Green;
                serbestMiktarSwitch.OnColor = Color.LightGray;
                stokCagirButton.TextColor = Color.Black;
                stokCagirButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            serbestMiktarBool = "1";
            serbestMiktarToogle = true;
            serbestMiktarSwitch.IsToggled = true;



        }




    }
```

I have to do that thing somehow, how can i fix this ?

Comment: It's unclear what else you do with the switch. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you Julian, I add some details to my question. This switch is very important.

Comment: Switch has Toggled event, and you could set the Preference value in the event. Then in page's OnAppearing method, get the newest value for Switch.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Switch has Toggled event, each time you IsToggled value changes, the event would fire. Then you could set the value for Preferences.

```
<Switch x:Name="serbestMiktarSwitch"   
                        IsToggled="False"
                        Toggled="serbestMiktarSwitch_Toggled" 
                         />
```

This is the ***serbestMiktarSwitch_Toggled*** event handler in code behind:

```
void serbestMiktarSwitch_Toggled(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    Switch s = sender as Switch;
    Preferences.Set("serbestMiktarTogle", e.Value);
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    serbestMiktarSwitch.IsToggled = Preferences.Get("serbestMiktarTogle", false);
}
```

If you still have any questions, feel free to ask me.

---

**Original post:**

I made a demo and you could have a try.

Suppose a button to controls the value of IsToggled.

Here is the ***xaml***:

```
<Button Text="Toggle Switch" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
<Switch x:Name="serbestMiktarSwitch"   
                         IsToggled="False"
                        Toggled="serbestMiktarSwitch_Toggled" 
                         />
```

For the ***code behind***:

```
//Change the value of switch on/off and save to preferences each time when the button clicks
void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Preferences.Set("serbestMiktarTogle", !Preferences.Get("serbestMiktarTogle", false));
}

// Each time the page start/appear, we get the value using Preferences (the default value is false)
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   serbestMiktarSwitch.IsToggled = Preferences.Get("serbestMiktarTogle", false);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I save string to this 'Preferences.Get("serbestMiktarTogle", false);'  When I open that page app crash instantly.  I update question with my function.

Comment: Why did you use type string for serbestMiktarBool? Why not use type bool for it?

Comment: Because you define serbestMiktarBool as string, when you get the default value false (type bool). Then it crashes.

Comment: @MertAltiparmak Hello, I add a new answer below to make a new demo based on your question. You could have a try.

Comment: Firstly, I'm sorry for my late answer. I could not make this work, Preferences does not take _true/false_ value.

Comment: Never mind. Please see this doc : [Storage types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=ios#supported-data-types). Preferences can store boolean value. We use it many times. My [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77140169/20118901) is an easy demo I just test. Please let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo based on this scenario, you may have a try.

First, the XAML is the same,

```
    <Switch x:Name="serbestMiktarSwitch"   
                             IsToggled="False"
                            Toggled="serbestMiktarSwitch_Toggled"               
                             />
```

Then for the code behind. Notice that **Preferences** can also store type boolean. That means we can use `Preferences.Set("serbestMiktarTogle", true or false)`. We don't have to store a string in it.

So I would do it in this way, each time the Switch toggled, I set the new value for Preferences:

```
    void serbestMiktarSwitch_Toggled(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.value is the present value for switch
        Preferences.Set("serbestMiktarTogle", e.Value);
        //then change the UI for Switch
        setSerbestMiktar();
    }
```

Here is the code for **setSerbestMiktar** method.

```
void setSerbestMiktar()
{
    

    //Notice here, I use false as a default value, you could set true if you want.
    bool serbestMiktarBool = Preferences.Get("serbestMiktarTogle", false);


    if (serbestMiktarBool == false)
    {
        serbestMiktarSwitch.IsToggled = false;
        serbestMiktarSwitch.ThumbColor = Color.Red;
        serbestMiktarSwitch.OnColor = Color.LightGray;

    }
    else if (serbestMiktarBool == true)
    {
        serbestMiktarSwitch.IsToggled = true;
        serbestMiktarSwitch.ThumbColor = Color.Green;
        serbestMiktarSwitch.OnColor = Color.LightGray;
    }
}
```

And on page start, we also have to set the Switch, so I add this:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        setSerbestMiktar();
    }
```

Hope it helps!